# public_schema_urlconfig not getting called using django-tenant-schema

Tags: python, django, schema, multi-tenant

I am new to multi tenancy & django. For my invoicing project, I'm using django-tenant-schemas. Now, I'm getting tenant websites up n running. However,its not working with a public client that I've created, with the domain of this public tenant being localhost, ie:

```
domain_url='{{ hostname }}'
```

and I've also set my

```
public_schema_urlconfig = 'invoicesolution.urls_public'
```

Now, my urls_public file is not getting called, although urls_tenant file gets called, which is in the same folder as the former.

What issue am I having? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

PS: I just edited the public_schema_urlconfig value to random things to see if the project breaks, however, it did not break.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer, but I had this exact same problem and just figured it out. You need to create a plublic tenant for your domain and then the urls will work. 
https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html